# youtube apikey that don't work in the night

Tags: youtube, api-key

I have a script that checks whether Youtube videos published on my site are active or not, this script uses Youtube API. From a few days it works perfectly from 9 am to 9 pm (Italian time zone) but from 9 pm onwards this message appears

Warning: file_get_contents(https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&id=R_aGssgzMnc&key=AIzaSyAIfZ4fZY3PbaCwj8p5UuZKmhv5rDbpdAA):

> failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden in
>   /web/htdocs/www.mysite.it/home/css/inc_check_video.php on line 95

the mystery (for me) is that from the next morning everything works again ... but how is it possible?

Comment: Maybe you're getting rate limited, which resets by your next morning?

Comment: thanks for the answer but this is not the problem: this script worked well for YEARS and only now in the last few days is it doing so!
If you want I write below a link of a page that now has WARNING while in 9 hours will have the video ->
https://www.pianetaproblemi.it/tutorial/video-guida-problemi-01.php